# Can Sonicwall TZ105W W0 port be configured as WAN?

Tags: sonicwall, wan

I need to setup a VPN with a remote location which has no wired Internet access. At the most we can get a GSM Wi-Fi hotspot for Internet access. I am hoping to install a SonicWall TZ105W and put W0 in the WAN zone to use the Wi-Fi hotspot as the WAN.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your GSM Wifi Hotspot has an Ethernet port you could connect **X1 (WAN)** there and it should work; that would be simplest.
If NOT then you will need to put **W0 (Wireless)** into *Wireless Bridge Mode*:

https://support.software.dell.com/kb/sw11099

However, in both cases, you will need to ensure the correct ports within GSM Wifi hotspot router are open for VPNs:

```
IPSec uses:
IP protocol 50 for ESP
IP protocol 51 for AH
UDP port 500 for IKE Phase 1 and Phase 2 negotiations
UDP port 4500 is used as well if NAT-T is enabled
```

That's to allow the remote site to initiate the connection, you would need to publish/NAT inbound those ports to the W0 interface if you wanted to initiate from the central office to the remote site.

I would suggest testing this before sending any equipment out as the little routers inside those hotspots are often troublesome. If it works please post back with the make and model.

Comment: If the GSM Wi-Fi Hotspot had an Ethernet port, I wouldn't be asking the question. We often do VPN from laptop using these Wi-Fi hotspots, so IPSec may work fine. But you have probably solved my problem, I didn't think about using it as a bridge. I should have, considering I have a half mile long Wi-Fi bridge between my home and office, setup using dd-wrt firmware on buffalo routers. I did that in 2007, still works fine.

Comment: Since some Hotspots have downlink ports and StackExchange is meant to serve as a reference to others as well I thought it worth mentioning (in case someone comes across this in the future).
Good luck with the bridging, let us know the results!